# Using a broadcast receiver to start AlarmManager in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I am writing a program that fires off an intent to start a service periodically, to do this I have decided to use alarmmanager, I was able to make this do what I wanted in an activity fairly easily but I'm getting an error when attempting to do it in a receiver that I'm unable to figure out.

`AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);`

tells me that **ALARM_SERVICE** can't be resolved to a variable

here is my complete code for that receiver:

```
package com.testapp21.second.activities;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class PhoneOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(context,
              0, new Intent(context, StatsCheckerService.class), 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
      long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

      // Schedule the alarm!
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                      firstTime, 30*1000, mAlarmSender);

}
}
```

Comment: When you say "ALARM_SERVICE can't be resolved to a variable" do you mean you get an exception at runtime or what?

Comment: Its an error in the compiler with a red underline, I assume it has something to do with the context being different in broadcast receivers but Im not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you are in a fragment you can do this

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
```